# I need to show a div on top of image :hover on hover

Tags: jquery, css

```
    .vpbutton {padding:4px;background-color:#EFEFEF;}
    .userbox img{padding:8px;background-color:#EFEFEF;}
    .userbox img:hover{opacity:.2;}
    <div class="userbox">
    <img src='img.png' style='height:120px;width:120px;border:1px solid #e5e5e5;'>
    </div>
    <div class="hello"> Hello</div>
```

I am trying to get the div with `class="hello"` to show centered on top of the image when someone hovers over it. any ideas please ?

Comment: Using jQuery for this will have better support than CSS `:hover` in IE6.

Comment: are we really still coding for IE6? I would suggest to forget about this, and hope this forces users to upgrade (prefarably to a non IE browser) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

while everyone was answering, i was making a jsfiddle of my own, also no javascript
http://jsfiddle.net/jCUNm/

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly... you want a div to appear on top of your image when you hover it, right?

If you mean how to show/hide it, I can think of two ways to do it. One with css, the other with jQuery.

**CSS:**

```
<a href="#" class="Anchor">
<img src='img.png' class="img">
<span class="Hello">hello</span>
</a>

a.anchor span.Hello {visibility:hidden;}
a.anchor:hover span.Hello {visibility:visible;}
```

And use some positioning (.Anchor would be relative, .Hello absolute, with the right z-index).

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.img').mouseover(function(){
     $('span.Hello').show();
   });
});
```

If you are wondering about the centering part, clarify :)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/eXSzJ/

I don't know if you are wondering about the centering, or the :hover, but heres how to do it with css

Comment: It has a flickery effect if you hover over "hello".

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/HXRsX/9/

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it with css with percentage values.

http://jsfiddle.net/rh6qW/5/

Answer (score 1):

A bit of the same with mouseover mouseout:

http://jsfiddle.net/wbrv5/

```
<div class="userbox">
    <img src='img.png'>
    <div class="hello" style="display:none"> Hello</div>
</div>

$('.userbox img').mouseover(function() {
  $(".hello").show();
});

$('.userbox img').mouseout(function() {
  $(".hello").hide();
});

.vpbutton {padding:4px;background-color:#EFEFEF;}

.userbox {position:relative;} .userbox img{height:120px;width:120px;border:1px solid
#e5e5e5;padding:8px;background-color:#EFEFEF; } .userbox img:hover{opacity:.2;}

.hello { position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I could do. The only restriction is that there can only be a single line of text. However, you could fairly easily convert this to do a few different things such as produce a div inside that is 80% of the width of the image, and center that div to allow for paragraph text.

JSBin Example at bottom.

**CSS**

```
    .vpbutton {
  padding:4px;
  background-color:#EFEFEF;
}
.userbox img{
  padding:8px;
  background-color:#EFEFEF;
  border:1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.userbox img:hover{
  opacity:.2;
}
.hover-text {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
}
.userbox img:hover ~ .hover-text {
  border:1px solid #000;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  display: block;

  text-align:center;

}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $('img[rel="hover-text"]').each(function () {
    this$ = $(this)
    console.log((this$.outerWidth() - this$.innerWidth()))
    this$.parent().find('.hover-text').css({
      'margin': (this$.outerWidth(true) - this$.width())+'px',
      'top':0,
      'left':0,
      'height': (this$.height())+'px',
      'width': (this$.width())+'px',
      'line-height':(this$.height())+'px'
    })
  })
})()
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="userbox">
    <img src='http://www.clonescriptsdb.com/scriptimages/inout-search-engine-google-like-search-engine-788.jpg' rel="hover-text">
    <div class="hover-text">asd</div>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/azuyol/13/edit

**UPDATE** to correctly account for margins/padding/borders.